# how to add Assembly info patcher in team city 7.1.5

Tags: teamcity

I'm using TeamCity 7.1.5 for my C#.net solutions and want to add Assembly info patcher feature, but i can't find it in Build Step Page, neither in Runner Type combobox where it has gone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its available on the Build step page once youve added a build step. - Additional build feature.